# Hide facebook login button when authenticated

Tags: android, facebook

I have been following the facebook tutorial on how to implement the "login flow", i have gotten the login and logout to work fine.

But my issue is that i want the login button to disappear when the user has been authenticated, the button is shown in the MainActivity, but when the user is logged in i want it to be hidden, and instead show up in my SettingsActivity. This is the code i have:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
SimpleLogin authClient = new SimpleLogin(ref, getActivity());

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
 // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_activity, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status"));
    authButton.setFragment(this);

    return view;
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        authClient.loginWithFacebook("91023888187238", session.getAccessToken(), new SimpleLoginAuthenticatedHandler() {
            public void authenticated(FirebaseSimpleLoginError error, FirebaseSimpleLoginUser user) {
                if(error != null) {

                    // There was an error

                }
                else {


                }
            }
        });
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        // Logged out of Facebook

    authClient.logout();
    }
}

}
```

I have tried adding this `authButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);` to the `if (state.isOpened()) {` but that caused error and the app crashed, any ideas how i could hide the loginbutton when the user is authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by saving the session token.

When I open my activity, ask by the token, if its there: check if it is OK. If its not or if no token was saved, then show login button.

When logging out, you should delete the token you saved! (i saved it in sharedPrefs)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @da_st can you please give some more details? when I try to do setVisibility(View.GONE), with keeping the access token in shared prefs, the button won't work after the login (instead of hiding itself)...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the UserSettingsFragment included in Facebook Android SDK. It's a fragment with Login button inside it.

When the user is successfully authenticated, you can hide/remove the fragment, and probably add the same fragment in another activity. (I'm not sure if that will work)

You could also just use Session.openActiveSession method to login instead of the Login button - then you can create a fragment with your own login button, hide it on successful authentication and show a logout button in your settings Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
button.post(new Runnable(){button.setVisibility()});
```

This will tell Android to set it with UI